# Transform the ERL in python

Tags: python, erl

Transform the ERL for one or more selection statements to decide whether a year is a Leap year.

The rules are:

A year is generally a Leap Year if it is divisible by 4, except that if the year is divisible by 100, it is not a Leap year, unless it is also divisible by 400.
Thus 1900 was not a Leap Year, but 2000 was a Leap year.

```
year = int(input ("What year would you like to assess? "))
leapYear = False #Setting a flag which will be assessed at the end
#the if statements are checking to see if the conditions #are true to assess it as a leap year
if year mod 4 == 0 then
leapYear = True
endif
if year mod 100 == 0 then
leapYear = False
end if
if year mod 400 == 0 then
leapYear = True
end if
if leapYear == True then
print("This is a leap year")
else
print("This is not a leap year")
end if
```

Comment: That's not Python. What is your actual question?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.